# PIL's Imagefromarray resulting in error when trying to convert from numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a simple image saved in the .bmp format.[image]

I'm using the following code to convert the pixels values into an np.array

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('C:\Desktop\sample_pic.bmp') 
pix = im.load()
im.show()
pixels=np.array(im.getdata())
```

The array shape is

```
(423099L,)
```

Now for simplicity purposes I"m going to use these array values when trying PIL's Imagefromarray function.

```
  im = Image.fromarray(pixels, mode ='P')
```

However, when running this code, I'm running into an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module>
    Image.fromarray(pixels, mode ='P')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2180, in fromarray
    size = shape[1], shape[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

So I tried changing the shape of the array, with the following code

```
x = pixels.reshape(1, 423099)
im =Image.fromarray(x, mode = 'P')
```

I'm able to run the code *now* without raising an error.
However when I run 
`im.show()` to see the pic..

I'm getting a pic with only a line running through the middle and not my original pic.

[image]

I want to be able to convert my original pic's values into an array, and then take the same array and be able to convert it to the imageformat .bmp using PIL's Imagefromarray.

Thanks.

EDIT: Even if I change the array to its original shape of 887 x 477 I'm getting a totally different picture from the original.

```
 y = pixels.reshape(887,477)
im = Image.fromarray(y, mode = 'P')
im.show()
```

resulting pic is

[image]

Comment: Well, you *told* PIL that it was a 1 x 423099 pixel image!  You need to shape the array with the actual dimensions of the image.

Comment: Thanks. However, I tried using the dimensions of the original image (887x 447)
`ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Comment: Whoops! It seems I made a mistake with the one of the dimensions. Everything works now!

Comment: Actually after further testing, when I'm resizing it to the original the array to the original dimensions, I'm getting a totally different picture.

Comment: You've got the width and height backwards, compared to the original image.  Perhaps the original was a pallet-based image, only using the first few colors - that would result in an image that was entirely dark shades of gray, considering that you didn't specify a palette for the resulting image.

Comment: It seems a PIL object stores the info backwards; so height first and then width.    I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a pallet-based image. 
The original pic is a white-background with the parallelogram figure.

Comment: You are throwing away the mode information of the original image.  If it is mode 'P' (which seems very likely), then its pixel data is meaningful only in terms of the image's color palette, which you also threw away.  You need to save and restore this with the ``getpalette``/``putpalette`` methods.

Comment: Thanks. I found a different way to take care of this problem temporarily,
`img = Image.open('C:\Desktop\sample_pic.jpeg').convert("RGB")` but I will play around with the suggestions you mentioned as well. Thank you.